# Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 445

Tags: errors, rel-canonical

After changing siteurl ,home url form database it shows 3/4 errors called

> Notice: Undefined index: host in
>   /var/www/html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 445
>
> Notice: Undefined index: scheme in
>   /var/www/html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 465
>
> Notice: Undefined index: host in
>   /var/www/html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 444
>
> Notice: Undefined index: host in
>   /var/www/html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 444

I have no idea whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I change the url from the database I just put forgot to keep http before the ip address . When I set the http it works fine here.

Answer (score 4):

As an update on this:
You can debug this by entering your WordPress Database table named "wp_options" and check for the tables "siteurl" and "home". These should reveal a mistake with your url (often http:// or https:// is not copied correctly).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in WordPress, scheduled for fix in v5.0:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34353

Comment: Now scheduled for being addressed in WordPress [v5.1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34353#comment:15)

Comment: Less than a week after the previous comment, the schedule [changed from 5.1 to Future Release](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34353#comment:17)