# After changing siteurl ,home url form database it shows 3/4 errors called

Tags: rel-canonical

> Notice: Undefined index: host in
>   /home/bhavani/public_html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 444

Comment: What did you change it to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Undefined index: host in /var/www/html/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 445](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246347/notice-undefined-index-host-in-var-www-html-wp-includes-canonical-php-on-line)